# Giving a fixed header a colour background

Tags: html, css, colors, background, header

I would like to give my fixed header a coloured background.  I have tried a few different ways, and I think there may be a simple answer but I just can't seem to find out what it is:

How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="LayoutDiv1"><h1>Hello</h1></div>
  <div id="LayoutDiv2"></div>
  <div id="LayoutDiv3"></div>
  <div id="LayoutDiv4"></div>
<div id="LayoutDiv9">Goodbye</div>

<div id="LayoutDiv10"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}

/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     5;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    10;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   25;

    Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
    http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

    and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
    http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 87.36%;
    padding-left: 1.82%;
    padding-right: 1.82%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv2 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv3 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4.1666%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv5 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4.1666%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv6 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4.1666%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv7 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4.1666%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv8 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4.1666%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv9 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv10 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 90.675%;
    padding-left: 1.1625%;
    padding-right: 1.1625%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv2 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv3 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5641%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv5 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5641%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv6 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5641%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv7 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5641%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv8 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5641%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv9 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#LayoutDiv10 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .gridContainer {
        width: 88.2%;
        max-width: 1232px;
        padding-left: 0.9%;
        padding-right: 0.9%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #LayoutDiv1 {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv2 {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv3 {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv4 {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 18.3673%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv5 {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2.0408%;
        width: 18.3673%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv6 {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2.0408%;
        width: 18.3673%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv7 {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2.0408%;
        width: 18.3673%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv8 {
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2.0408%;
        width: 18.3673%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv9 {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #LayoutDiv10 {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    }

    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    #LayoutDiv1 {
        position: fixed;
        height: 50px;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10000;
        background:#FFF;
    }

    #LayoutDiv2 {
        position: fixed;
        height: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10002;
        background:#FFF;
        }

    #LayoutDiv3 {

        margin-top: 135px;

        }

    #LayoutDiv9 {
        position: fixed;
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index:10006;
        background:#FFF;
        max-height: 100px;
        bottom: 60px;
        }

    #LayoutDiv10 {

        position: fixed;
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index:10008;
        background:#FFF;
        bottom:0px;
        max-height: 60px;
        }
```

Comment: Where abouts is the header you are trying to colour in your HTML code?

What div is it?

Comment: I just want the first div to have a blue background, while the text in the first div remains black.

Comment: you mean `background-color`? for `LayoutDiv1`?

Comment: @AndrewSmith: That sounds very simple. did you try `background-color: blue`? did it not work?

Comment: great thankyou, why does it leave small white gap between the left side of the screen and where it starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#LayoutDiv1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

**background is set to white that's why you can't see it**

**ONE MORE THING** - this line is at the bottom of your stylesheet so it will override all your style

Here's my fiddle i just copy paste your code and replace the bakcground color to blue - http://jsfiddle.net/SHeWm/

Comment: Great thankyou, do you happen to know why it leaves a white gap between the left hand side of the screen and the beginning of the blue  background in Div 1?

Comment: your body is somehow calling a user agent that adds margin:8px

Comment: Is this part of the "mass-n00bocide" mentioned at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/ ? The white gap comes from setting a width on the content and then centering it. And about the answer: *"this line is at the bottom of your stylesheet so it will override all your style"* -- this is not true, there is no conflict with other rules as far as the `background-color` is concerned...

Comment: nope this is true @xec see the first style for #LayoutDiv1 (He did not specified a media for that) see comment /* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

Comment: @markvicencio I think I see what you're getting at, but it's still quite unclear from reading the answer. As far as the white gap goes, see http://jsfiddle.net/SHeWm/1/ where I commented out the `.gridContainer` rules (width, centering and padding) and also removed the native margin on `<body>`

Comment: i know where the white gap comes: the display: block for body. try override it with display: inline-block; but this is not a clean solution.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, please don't make the `<body>` `inline-block`! The only reason that would "work" is because of side-effects it's extremely unlikely the OP (or anyone else) would ever want (or need)